# angularjs how to use use the option select

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been tinkering around with AngularJS lately and i've ran into a bit of trouble. I have a form in which users can select 3 options:

```
   <select name="multipleSelect" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="data.multipleSelect">
            <option value="eenmalig" ng-click=data()>Eenmalig</option>
            <option value="maandelijks" ng-click=data()>Maandelijks</option>
            <option value="wekelijks" ng-click=data()>Wekelijks</option>
          </select>
        </label>
```

Now, depending on which one they select, certain things would need to show up or not..

```
            <label class="item item-input" ng-show="showDateInput">
        <span class="input-label" >Start datum</span>
        <input type="date"> 
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" ng-show="showDateInput">
        <span class="input-label">Eind datum</span>
        <input type="date">
        </label>
```

So, the input of the 3 options would need to determine if these date inputs will show up.

After trying lots of things, I ended up having this in my controller

```
 $scope.data = function(data){
 multipleSelect: []

 if($scope.data.multipleSelect === "wekelijks"){
showDateInput = true;
 }
 if($scope.data.multipleSelect === "maandelijks"){
showDateInput = true;
 }
 };
$scope.showDateInput = false;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Bunch of thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-change in select tag. in options ng-click can't work and try the below code

```
<select name="multipleSelect" ng-change="data()" id="multipleSelect" ng-model="data.multipleSelect">
            <option value="eenmalig" >Eenmalig</option>
            <option value="maandelijks">Maandelijks</option>
            <option value="wekelijks">Wekelijks</option>
          </select>
        </label>
```

in controller

```
$scope.data = function(data){
 if($scope.data.multipleSelect === "wekelijks" || $scope.data.multipleSelect === "maandelijks"){
   $scope.showDateInput = true;
 } else {
   $scope.showDateInput = false;
  }

 };
$scope.showDateInput = false;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you alot! I totally forgot about ng-change.. I am quite new :) And I forgot about the || AND operators xD Thank you for helping out. greatly appreciated!